# How to call function on animation interrupt in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a player character that has a roll animation and attack animation. Both animation can be triggered in any state. So when player is in rolling animation, user can press attack button and interrupt rolling animation before it is finished. I want to call a function if rolling animation interrupted. How can achieve this? I can call a function by adding event at the end of the animation and detect if it is finished but I could not find a way how to detect if it is interrupt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click into the Animator, click on the Roll state. In the Inspector, at the bottom there is a button to Add Behaviour. looks like

[image: this].

Click the Add Behaviour and create a RollState. Then it will look like this:
[image]

Double click the RollState script. In here you can write the interupption using its OnStateUpdate and OnStateExit. Just uncomment the lines to use it. [image: Sample]

Answer (score 0):

Since the transition happens on a button press by the player, you can call the function on button press.

Alternatively you can use the State machine OnStateExit function using the behaviour script.